# Intel I5 12500H underperforming

Tags: cpu, performance, benchmarking

I have recently purchased a new laptop with Intel I5 12500H inside. I bought it as a replacement for my older laptop that had Ryzen 7 5700U inside.

Most benchmarks show that Intel should outperform AMD in single-core performance by ~30-50% depending on the benchmark.
However, I am not seeing that in my day-to-day work.

Old machine shows 16GB of DDR4 SDRAM 1600 MHz in Dual-channel setup when I check in HWInfo. New (Dell XPS 9520 with NVME SSD) has 64GB of DDR5 SDRAM. On Dell website is says it should be Dual-channel @4800 MHz but in HWInfo I see that it shows as Quad-channel and clocked at 2400MHz.

I work as a software dev, and we have some CPU-intensive tests that run single-threaded.
The runtime of them on my new laptop is pretty much the same as it was on my older one. Sometimes it even takes longer.

I tried running a benchmark from [cpu.userbenchmark.com](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/) to see if it was Intel underperforming or AMD overperforming, but it gave wildly inconsistent results.
Both CPUs would get wildly different scores between runs (+-25%) which was not very helpful.

I ran a Geekbench benchmark. It shows consistent scores between runs and it shows a very decent improvement (within the 30-50% range) on the Intel side. Average single core scores over 3-4 runs were (higher is better):

```
ryzen: 1484
intel: 2049
```

This confused me, as it shows that Intel is supposedly much faster, yet I am not seeing it in my day-to-day work.

As a test, I wrote my own benchmark which is very trivial. I have 3 use cases:

1. function that calculates Nth Fibonacci number recursively (single-threaded)
2. a `for` loop that calculates a sum of numbers from 1 to X(single-threaded)
3. sum of numbers from 1 to X but using all cores (multi-threaded)

All benchmark computations are done in memory and nothing gets read/written to disk. For each of the cases, I picked 2 sets of parameters so that 1st completes in ~10 seconds and the second completes in ~1min.

After each bench I let the laptops cool for ~5 mins to normal temp before starting the next benchmark.
The average results from ~10 runs were as follows (score is time in ms that it took to complete the work, so lower is better):

```
fibonacci #46
ryzen: 9196
intel: 9952


fibonacci #50
ryzen: 63489
intel: 64927

sum normal 40_000_000_000
ryzen: 9291
intel: 11767

sum normal 250_000_000_000
ryzen: 58220
intel: 73341

sum parallel 250_000_000_000
ryzen: 7885
intel: 7258

sum parallel 2_000_000_000_000
ryzen: 69193
intel: 62742
```

This shows that Ryzen outperforms Intel in all single-threaded benchmarks.
Intel outperforms Ryzen in multi-core, but barely.

Please help me figure out why am I not seeing the same gains as the ones depicted in Geekbench/other online benchmarks.
Maybe some setting I am missing?

Both laptops have Win11 with all updates installed.
Both laptops are set to balanced performance in windows settings.
Both are on AC power.
No overclocking of any kind was done.
No other apps were running during benchmarking.

Comment: Did you put the faster CPU in a machine with a slow (5400-rpm) hard drive?

Comment: I doubt this is hard drive related, as all benchmark computations are done in memory and nothing gets read/written to disk. The laptop with Intel is a Dell XPS 9520 with nvme SSD.

Comment: Thanks for the drive update.   Maybe run Admin Tools, Resource Monitor and see if that helps you.

Comment: Does the new machine have single channel ram while the old has dual channel?

Comment: Old machine shows 16GB of DDR4 SDRAM 1600 MHz in Dual-channel setup when I check in HWInfo. New has 64GB of DDR5 SDRAM. On Dell website is says it should be Dual-channel @4800 MHz but in HWInfo I see that it shows as Quad-channel and clocked at 2400MHz

Comment: I am not shocked that performance is better with a system with DDR5 compared to DDR4. You are also not comparing Intel vs AMD against the same processor generation.

Comment: I think you are misreading. Intel machine has DDR5 and is slower in single-core in my benchmarks. You are right I am not comparing same generations, but Intel came 1 year after Ryzen chip, so it's next gen and I expect it to be faster. I am not even talking about the fact that Intel is H series while Ryzen is U.

Comment: Welcome to SU. It's a bit difficult to evaluate what might be going wrong. Could you [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1769915/edit) the question to clarify what settings you're referring to? Adding your benchmarker might also help. In general it's better to add new info / clarifications / etc. by editing the question than putting it in comments, as this keeps everything relevant readily available. No need now, as I already added what you've told. Looking at the RAM info; I think Dell might be internally doing something odd - have you contacted their support?